# AWS Lambda hanging on specific GET call

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios

I have a simple AWS Lambda doing two calls - One to SWAPI (Star Wars API) and one to the NASDAQ website. Both work locally, but in AWS Lambda, only the SWAPI call resolves and the NASDAQ call hangs until the Lambda function times out. Is it possible that the NASDAQ website is blocking the call? How can I confirm this? (Note: no errors show up when running, just hanging).

Here is the code:

```
import axios from "axios";

export interface Event {
  name: string;
}

const main = async (): Promise<string> => {
  try {
    console.log(
      (
        await axios({
          url: "https://swapi.co/api/people/2",
          method: "GET",
          responseType: "blob"
        })
      ).data
    );

    console.log(
      (
        await axios({
          url:
            "https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download",
          method: "GET",
          responseType: "blob"
        })
      ).data
    );

    return "Success";
  } catch (e) {
    `Failed + ${e}`;
  }
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "DEV") {
  main();
}

export default main;
```

Comment: Your catch isn't doing anything. Change the `Failed + ${e};` line to `console.error(e)` and you should see if there are any errors. The issue may be deeper than that though: with lambda functions, you should export the function as `handler`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

Comment: @AndyMardell thanks for the response. I fixed `Failed + ${e};` but still no incite on why it's hanging. When it comes to `handler`, I have the lambda function configured to look for main so that isn't the issue.